# Who divided the Tehillim into days?

Tags: history, calendar, tehilim-psalms

Who divided the Sefer Tehillim into daily sections (both day of week and day of month)?

Comment: [Very related.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30402) (This asks who did it and that asks why.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The division of Tehilim into days of the week and days of the month was done by the 14th century scholar [Rabbeinu Menachem ben Zorach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menahem_ben_Aaron_ibn_Zerah), a Talmid of Rabbeinu Yehuda ben HaRosh.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39362&st=&pgnum=256

> וכבר חלקתי ספר תהילים לאמר חלק ממנו בבל יום ויום בענין שיקראהו המתנדב
>   לשבח ולהודות בכל חדש פעם אחת והנני כוחב אחר פרק זה החילוק שבכל יום
>   מהחדש וכן החילוק שחלקתיו גם לקרותו פעם אחח בכל שבוע למי שעסקי תורתו
>   מועטת שישתדל לקרותו בכל שבוע

This is the link showing the divisions - http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39362&st=&pgnum=263

---

@Alex points out:

> It's also interesting that our present-day divisions don't always follow Rabbeinu Menachem's: he has the portion for the 4th of the month end with ch. 30 (whereas we now end with 28), for the 18th he has chs. 88-90 (where we now do 88-89), for the 20th he ends with ch. 102 (where we now also add 103), and for the 26th he has the second half of ch. 119 plus chs. 120-122 (nowadays we just do 119). There are also differences in the weekly division.

Comment: Chabad.org has two different entries from Talks and Tales on their website. One calls him Ben Ibn Zorach, and one calls him Ben Zerach. One says he lived a long life, and one says he didn't. http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/112352/jewish/Rabbi-Menachem-Ben-Ibn-Zorach.htm and http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/112341/jewish/Rabbi-Menachem-Ibn-Zerach.htm

Comment: @Gershon: most interesting, thanks. It's also interesting that our present-day divisions don't always follow Rabbeinu Menachem's: he has the portion for the 4th of the month end with ch. 30 (whereas we now end with 28), for the 18th he has chs. 88-90 (where we now do 88-89), for the 20th he ends with ch. 102 (where we now also add 103), and for the 26th he has the second half of ch. 119 plus chs. 120-122 (nowadays we just do 119). There are also differences in the weekly division. I wonder on whose authority those changes were made?