# Why are the daily tehilim divided as they are?

Tags: minhag, calendar, tehilim-psalms

How were the daily starting and ending points for weekly and monthly readings of all of tehilim chosen? Are they just chosen to make them all approximately the same length, or are there specific reasons why certain points are chosen?

Comment: [Very related.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9253) (That asks who did it and this asks why.)