# tehillim division not equal lengths

Tags: calendar, tehilim-psalms

What is the logic behind the unequal divisions of Tehillim into days of the month; the sections are of very varying lengths i.e. the "longest days" are twice the length of the "shortest days?"

Comment: Yehudis Hendry, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you get good answers, and that you also check out some of our other stuff, perhaps starting with our 100+ other [tag:tehilim-psalms] questions. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: This might be a good place to start looking for an answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9261/603

Comment: The original divisions that you noted would be more equal.  I wonder if publishers could go back to it?

Answer (score 1):

The division of the Tehillim is not meant to be *just* a way to say the entire Tehillim over the course of a month, rather it was split like this because each day of the month is different and has its own path to follow in the service of Hashem. Each days chapters' are special for that day.

Similarly, the Psalm of the day (which the Leveim sang in the Beis Hamikdash) for Wednesday is at least twice as long as the one for Friday. Each day is special and has a special way to serve Hashem.

Comment: Hi WhyEnBe. Can you [edit] your post to source your claims?

Comment: So why are the daily tehillim read in order? If they were special for the day, one might think that each day's tehillim should be selected from throughout.

Comment: Ok, will do.

The order they are in is also for a reason. Not Chronological. See here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35021/source-for-book-of-tehillim-out-of-order

Comment: @WhyEnBe I'm not saying their order isn't for a reason. I'm just suggesting that the reason might not be for the convenience of reading them in order during the monthly cycle. Can you show some evidence that that's the reason the tehillim are in the order that they are (as opposed to any other reason)?